# No logs captured in kafka topic with filebeat config

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubectl, filebeat

I am new to the Filebeat, Logstash, Kafka, ElasticSearch stack where the logs are captured and processed.
Recently I have been working on this filebeat configuration in the filebeat-daemonset.yaml file in the master node of a cluster.

This is the configuration :

```
# default filebeat_expire_time is 30 days


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.config.inputs:
      enabled: true
      path: /etc/filebeat.yml
      reload.enabled: true
      reload.period: 10s

    filebeat.registry.flush: 60s

    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      exclude_files: [".*_kube-system_.*", ".*_monitoring_.*", ".*_argo_.*"]
      close_removed: false

    processors:
    - script:
        lang: javascript
        id: js_filter
        source: >
          function process(event) {
              // extract pod metadata
              var path = event.Get("log").file.path;
              var kube_uid = path.substring(20, path.length-4); // /var/log/containers/KUBE_UID.log
              event.Put("kube_uid", kube_uid);
              var segments = kube_uid.split("_");
              event.Put("kube_pod_name", segments[0]);
              event.Put("kube_namespace_name", segments[1]);
              event.Put("container_name", segments[2].substring(0, segments[2].length-65));
              event.Put("container_id", segments[2].substring(segments[2].length-64));

              // drop useless fields
              event.Delete("agent");
              event.Delete("ecs");
              event.Delete("host");
              event.Delete("log");
              event.Delete("input");

              // rename message fields
              var message = event.Get("message");
              event.Put("log", message);
              event.Delete("message");

              // convert timestamp field
              event.Put("time", event.Get("@timestamp"));
              event.Put("time_milli_long", Math.round(event.Get("@timestamp").UnixNano() / 1000000));
              event.Put("time_nano_long", event.Get("@timestamp").UnixNano());
              // add time filter
              if (event.Get("time_milli_long") < Date.now() - 43200 * 60 * 1000 ) {
                event.Cancel();
              }
          }
    - add_fields:
        target: ""
        fields:
          host: ${NODE_NAME}
          es_index: "k8s_log_ai_prod"

    output.kafka:
      # initial brokers for reading cluster metadata
      hosts:
      - "kafka-las-share-01.server.hulu.com:6667"
      - "kafka-las-share-02.server.hulu.com:6667"
      - "kafka-las-share-03.server.hulu.com:6667"
      - "kafka-las-share-04.server.hulu.com:6667"
      - "kafka-las-share-05.server.hulu.com:6667"
      version: "0.10.2"

      # message topic selection + partitioning
      topic: "vai-caposv2-prod-las"

      worker: 8
      required_acks: 1
      compression: none
      max_message_bytes: 1000000
      bulk_max_size: 2048
      channel_buffer_size: 4096
      keep_alive: 60

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: Default
      tolerations:
        - operator: Exists
      containers:
        - name: filebeat
          image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.11.1
          args: [
            "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
            "-e",
          ]
          env:
            - name: NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 4
              memory: 2Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
              readOnly: true
              subPath: filebeat.yml
            - name: data
              mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
            - name: varlibdockercontainers
              mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
              readOnly: true
            - name: varlog
              mountPath: /var/log
              readOnly: true
            - name: varlib-mount-dockercontainers
              mountPath: /mnt/volume1/docker/docker/containers
              readOnly: true
            - name: varlib-mount-cricontainers
              mountPath: /mnt/volume1/docker/pods-log
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 0640
            name: filebeat-config
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
        # data folder stores a registry of read status for all files, so we don't send everything again on a Filebeat pod restart
        - name: data
          hostPath:
            # When filebeat runs as non-root user, this directory needs to be writable by group (g+w).
            path: /var/lib/filebeat-data
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
        - name: varlib-mount-dockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /mnt/volume1/docker/docker/containers
        - name: varlib-mount-cricontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /mnt/volume1/docker/pods-log
```

This filebeat-daemonset.yaml file was already existing in the master node. I just applied this by using this command :

`kubectl apply -f filebeat-daemonset.yaml`

After running this I can see the filebeat pods running on all the nodes in the cluster -

```
vai.deploy@caposv2-prod-ai-master01:/opt$ kubectl get daemonset -n kube-system
NAME                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
calico-node                      34        34        33      34           33          <none>          164d
filebeat                         34        34        33      34           33          <none>          23d
nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset   10        10        9       10           9           <none>          176d
```

And I can see the logs being captured in one set of nodes whose names start are like 'ai-general-xx' but I cannot see the logs from the other nodes whose names are like 'vai-computing-con-xxx'.

I describe the node using `kubectl describe node vai-computing-con-012`
And I can see the filebeat pod running in one of the vai-computing-con nodes.

```
Non-terminated Pods:          (7 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                              CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                              ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 calico-node-gn6pc                                 250m (0%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         164d
  kube-system                 filebeat-4pft9                                    100m (0%)     4 (3%)      100Mi (0%)       2Gi (0%)       19d
  monitoring                  node-exporter-fzflb                               112m (0%)     270m (0%)   200Mi (0%)       220Mi (0%)     167d
  nimbus                      caposv2-3606523f4cd84c25b392d8a66d12647d-lx2t9    8 (7%)        0 (0%)      64Gi (8%)        64Gi (8%)      6h26m
  nimbus                      caposv2-7864b8706ee74e3fb3fdec4529587196-7jxwt    16 (15%)      0 (0%)      180Gi (23%)      180Gi (23%)    83m
  rook-ceph-admin             csi-cephfsplugin-8xnls                            0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         167d
  rook-ceph-admin             csi-rbdplugin-p2gxm                               0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         167d
```

I can also see the logs being captured when I executed this command : `kubectl logs filebeat-4pft9 -n kube-system`
And I see no errors when I looked into the logs. Here is a part of the logs -

```
2024-01-09T16:41:41.517Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cgroup":{"cpu":{"stats":{"periods":8}},"cpuacct":{"total":{"ns":22051632}},"memory":{"mem":{"usage":{"bytes":-155648}}}},"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":5260,"time":{"ms":2}},"total":{"ticks":14150,"time":{"ms":23},"value":14150},"user":{"ticks":8890,"time":{"ms":21}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1048576},"open":9},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"95411b4f-6455-4547-be4d-42d3b86bd48c","uptime":{"ms":33210056}},"memstats":{"gc_next":21179168,"memory_alloc":10662112,"memory_total":930745080,"rss":69300224},"runtime":{"goroutines":23}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0},"scans":3},"output":{"events":{"active":0}},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":0}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}},"system":{"load":{"1":0.78,"15":0.74,"5":0.64,"norm":{"1":0.0075,"15":0.0071,"5":0.0062}}}}}}
2024-01-09T16:42:11.517Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cgroup":{"cpu":{"stats":{"periods":12}},"cpuacct":{"total":{"ns":8068913}},"memory":{"mem":{"usage":{"bytes":-163840}}}},"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":5260,"time":{"ms":6}},"total":{"ticks":14160,"time":{"ms":8},"value":14160},"user":{"ticks":8900,"time":{"ms":2}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1048576},"open":9},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"95411b4f-6455-4547-be4d-42d3b86bd48c","uptime":{"ms":33240056}},"memstats":{"gc_next":21179168,"memory_alloc":11488064,"memory_total":931571032,"rss":69300224},"runtime":{"goroutines":23}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0},"scans":3},"output":{"events":{"active":0}},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":0}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}},"system":{"load":{"1":0.86,"15":0.75,"5":0.67,"norm":{"1":0.0083,"15":0.0072,"5":0.0064}}}}}}
2024-01-09T16:42:41.517Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cgroup":{"cpu":{"stats":{"periods":9}},"cpuacct":{"total":{"ns":6832351}}},"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":5270,"time":{"ms":6}},"total":{"ticks":14170,"time":{"ms":8},"value":14170},"user":{"ticks":8900,"time":{"ms":2}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1048576},"open":9},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"95411b4f-6455-4547-be4d-42d3b86bd48c","uptime":{"ms":33270057}},"memstats":{"gc_next":21179168,"memory_alloc":12444280,"memory_total":932527248,"rss":69300224},"runtime":{"goroutines":23}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0},"scans":3},"output":{"events":{"active":0}},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":0}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}},"system":{"load":{"1":0.59,"15":0.73,"5":0.62,"norm":{"1":0.0057,"15":0.007,"5":0.006}}}}}}
2024-01-09T16:43:11.517Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cgroup":{"cpu":{"stats":{"periods":10}},"cpuacct":{"total":{"ns":8659954}}},"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":5280,"time":{"ms":6}},"total":{"ticks":14180,"time":{"ms":7},"value":14180},"use^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 kubectl logs filebeat-4pft9 -n kube-system
```

But I could not see the logs coming from this node being captured in the kafka topic that is specified in the filebeat-daemonset.yaml file.

What and where do I need to look into to get the logs from all nodes to be captured in the kafka topic? What needs to be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried changing the output to write to local files. I ask this because if Filebeat is able to successfully write transformed logs to local files, then the issue is with the Filebeat to Kafka connection. However, if the logs cant be written locally, then there might be an issue with the processing of the files. Once you verify that the transformed files can be written locally and transformed, then check the connection.